# Should I drop and recreate indexes if I truncate and insert data into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, ssms

I'd like to know, if i have a table with indexes and I want to truncate the table and insert new data into the table, should I drop the indexes and recreate them?
or should i just leave the indexes? will it make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the index and truncate the table if you are dealing with small number of records. Also you need to check the index fragmentation level after your data processing.  If you see the high fragmentation then you need to rebuild the indexes.
if you are trying to insert large number of rows to the table that has indexes then it may longer time.  Drop the index and create it after you insert the data will give you much performance.

Comment: Also, note that "large" is a very subjective measure, and depends on tons of factors, such as storage backend IO capabilities, width of table, data types, jagged/consistent row length, index type, index sorting, index keys, concurrent load on the system, etc...  In general, the short answer to your question is "yes, it will make a difference." The "heavier" the table is, the more the rest of the answer leans toward "and you should go ahead and drop the indexes and recreate them afterward." Truncate the table before you drop the indexes - it'll be friendlier to the transaction log.